# How do I make a tile in WinJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, winjs, live-tile

I'm using WinJS 4.4.3 to make a web app. And I'm trying to recreate the Start Menu/Screen. I haven't seen any tutorials on the web or even on Microsoft's website (new or former playground) that shows how to do something like [this](https://metroui.org.ua/templates/start-screen.html). Also, I'd like the push animation those tiles display. If there is a way to make tiles like that, is there an animation similar to that?

So in short, how do I make a tile in WinJS (web)?

Answer (score 0):

I just used MetroUICSS to create the tiles. It's much easier. WinJS documentation for making web apps (not store apps) is lacking. The relevant information is hidden away. For anyone who maybe interested. [Tiles in grid layout.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465463.aspx)